# Why android program doesnt work on my phone( it work on virtual phone fine)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
 try {
        val adresstext= findViewById(R.id.editText3)as TextView

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
                location -> location

            var locationx=location.longitude
            var locationy=location.latitude

            val name = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
            name.text=(locationx.toString()+" "+locationy.toString())
            var geocoder: Geocoder
            var listadress :List<Address>


            geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            listadress =geocoder.getFromLocation(locationy,locationx,1)
            var adress=listadress[0].getAddressLine(0)
            var city =listadress[0].locality.get(0)
            var state = listadress[0].adminArea.get(0)
            var country = listadress[0].getCountryName()
            var postalCode = listadress[0].getPostalCode()
            var knownName = listadress[0].getFeatureName()
            adresstext.text=(adress+city+state+country+postalCode+knownName)


        }

    }
    catch (e: java.lang.Exception)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

That is my code,
when ı run it in the emulator it works fine with no error 
But when i run it with my phone( ı connect it to my pc) the button not working and it says :

```
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
D/AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=19134
```

Before that when the program opens in my phone the run seciton is like :

```
E/: APS:IFLoad:importExternalFunctions, search function createNewHwApsUtils failed, dlsym err:undefined symbol: createNewHwApsUtils

E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@6c8edde
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@3bb1bbf
```

this 3 are red How can i solve that problem?

Comment: I see, you use to location services in your code. Are you sure your phone allow to use location permission?

Comment: in manifest i add the permission line for phone do ı need to add something else like give the permission alert and click allow for it?

Comment: No, you dont need to use permission alert. Just go to settings and find your application. Check location service is allowed or not.

Comment: oo i see my phone declines it.

Comment: Okay nice, i write it to answer area, I would be glad if you approve of my answer. Kolay gelsin.

Comment: Thank You I give the permission for it and know it works fine. Teşekkürler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to phone settings and find your application. Check location service is allowed. If not allowed. Accept that.